# Question about simple grammer of Class constructor method

Tags: c++

```
class Entity {
public:
    std::string GetName() { return "Entity:"; }
};

class Player : public Entity {
private :
    std::string m_name;

public :
    Player(const std::string& name) : m_name(name) {}

    std::string GetName() { return m_name; }


};
```

above is C++ class definition i'm studying currently. Everthing looks OK but i don't understand the part,

```
Player(const std::string& name) : m_name(name) {}
```

Why do I need `: m_name(name)` part? what is the use of that definition?
So far what I understood is that it changes the variable `m_name` to be the parameter `name` of Player constructor... is that it?

Comment: Which C++ textbook are you "studying"? Doesn't it have a chapter on constructors and class member initialization?

Comment: Studying code is only a small fraction of the game. You MUST get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) if you really want to learn C++ in a reasonable timeframe. It's too complicated a language to try to muddle your way though with code samples found on the Internet.

Comment: @user4581301 that is so true. I must find a good source and start from there to master it.. Thank you!